# Geolocation with vuejs and firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store the geolocation points (latitude and longitude) in firestore database.
So I created a new object called `acctPosition` in `vueJs` to store there the geopoints then I `console.log` it out and get as error:

`Cannot read property 'acctPosition' of null at eval (Geolocation.vue?dc3a:148)`

line 148 is `var acctPos = this.acctPosition.push(pos)`

Geolocation component:

```
    ...

    data () {
       ... 
       coords: {
         latitude: null,
         longitude: null
       },
       acctPosition: [],
       ... 
    }

    mounted () {
    ...

    var self = this;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          console.log(pos)
          map.setCenter(pos);
          var acctPos = self.acctPosition.push(pos)
          console.log(acctPos)
        }
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      }


      let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`

      // store geoData to currentUser in firebase firestore
      fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set({
        acctPosition: this.acctPosition
      }).then(ref => {
        console.log('work')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })


   },
   ...
```

After this I wrote the code to store this in firebase but I got `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside is not `Vue` instance. You can do a trick by assign `self = this` or using arrow function:

```
   mounted () {
    ...
     var self = this;
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          console.log(pos)
          map.setCenter(pos);
          var acctPos = self.acctPosition.push(pos)
          console.log(acctPos)

          let docId = `${self.currentUser.uid}`

          // store geoData to currentUser in firebase firestore
          fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set({
            acctPosition: self.acctPosition
          }).then(ref => {
            console.log('work')
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
        }
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      }
}
```

Comment: But the upload to firestore won't work, how to do this?

Comment: So I mean the upload is working but its nothing stored 
except the empty array of acctPosition

Comment: I've updated the answer. Javascript is asynchronously, so `fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set()` is execute before `getCurrentPosition` is finished.